# How to Identify Field Usage in Page Layouts

Tags: deployment

We are cleaning up our environment and would like to know which fields are not being used in a Page Layout. Does anybody know of an app that can accomplish this for us ? Ideally, there would be one which would give a list of all the fields and the Page Layouts they are being used in - and the ones which are blank could (possibly) be deleted.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**App.** The [SnapShot](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YhyEAE) app appears to have a reporting feature that might meet your requirements, I've not used it personally, but might be worth taking a look.

> Rich reporting & analysis
>   Compare/diff orgs, document data dictionary of objects and fields, map complex relationships (e.g. profiles to page layouts, fields to reports, picklist instances), and much more.

**Homebrew.** Coding this is a tricky one, as direct references alone on a Layout will not be enough to achieve your goal. For example you could have formula fields references and beyond that workflow or validation rules? However if you do want an initial steer layout wise, you could use the Metadata API to export the fields and layouts in XML form and write some code to parse and reconcile the information. This requires some scripting / programming skills in XML.